# Is there a way to "plot" a dataframe as a table with different colours for each cell containing a specific string?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently using pyplot to show three plots and a table (with strings in each cell) in a pop-up window. I would like to add colours to the cells according to the string in them.

Here is what i currently have, adapted to fit an example:

- The plots (these are done): The function receives 12 dataframes (xi_j, yi_j) which have the position of the contestants of a race in space (x) and time (y) for different segments of the race track. These are plotted in three plots.
- The table (the issue): The function receives an additional dataframe (race_order) that has the race track segments as columns, and the names of contestants in order of who was fastest in that segment in each cell.

The code I currently have, without any colour in the table:

```
# x1, y1 - curves
# x2, y2 - lines
# race_df - dataframe with position for each contestant
# race_order - dataframe with name of contestants organized by position in race for each segment

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,3,1) # Plot 1
plt.plot(y1_1,x1_1)
plt.plot(y2_1,x2_1)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Position')

plt.subplot(2,3,2) # Plot 2
plt.plot(y1_2,x1_2)
plt.plot(y2_2,x2_2)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Position')

plt.subplot(2,3,3) # Plot 3
plt.plot(y1_3,x1_3)
plt.plot(y2_3,x2_3)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Position')
plt.legend(x1_1.columns, prop ={'size': 8})

plt.subplot(2,1,2) # Table
cell_text = []
for row in range(len(race_order)):
    cell_text.append(race_order.iloc[row])  
table = plt.table(cellText = race_order.values,colLabels = race_order.columns,loc='center')
table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.set_fontsize(8)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

The pop up window shows this (text edited to match example):

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Itj.png)

I would like to have this but with each name having a colour associated, so it is easier to see the general trend with a glance:

[Table with colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlTHX.png)

I have tried to adapt a bunch of different solutions I found online (mostly using dataframe styles), but I am fairly new to Python so I couldn't get to this at all.

The number of contestants and the contestants names change from race to race, but I am fine with setting the colours manually for each race if there is no way to do it automatically. I would also like the colours in the table to match those in the plot, but if that's not feasible any colour will do.

If this does not work with pyplot and there is a better/easier alternative to do this, that is also good. My goal here is just to be able to see the plots and table at the same time on screen.

Thank you!

EDIT:
A quick correction: y1 and x2 are series and not dataframes.

Here are examples of the dataframes and series used. x1 and y1 were shortened in length for readability, and the other only show 3 segments for the same reason, but the table is always done for 11 segments/columns.

All x1, y1, x2, and y2 are the same but with different values:

```
# x1
index  Kate  Bruce Linda Tim Cory
0      0     0     0.4   0   0
1      0.9   0.4   0.8   0.4 0
2      1.3   0.9   1.3   0.9 0.4
3      2.2   1.3   1.7   1.3 1.3
4      2.6   1.3   2.2   1.7 1.7
5      3     2.2   2.6   2.1 2.2
6      3.4   2.6   3     2.5 2.6
#            ... 
# cut for readability

# y1
index  time
0      0
1      1.5
2      3
3      4.5
4      6
5      7.5
6      9
#            ... 
# cut for readability

# x2
index  position
0      10
1      20
2      40
3      60

# y2
index  Kate  Bruce Linda Tim Cory
0      33    31    31    34  33
1      58    59    60    54  64
2      69    74    77    69  79
3      81    88    92    84  95

# race_order
index  Segment 1  Segment 2 Segment 3
0      Kate       Kate      Bruce
1      Bruce      Tim       Kate
2      Tim        Bruce     Cory
3      Cory       Cory      Tim
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your dataframes for a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @mozway Added! Thank you

Comment: It is still a bit difficult to run you example as one needs to copy paste each Series/DataFrame. Ideally, you should post a self-sustaining code that can just be copy pasted to run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cellColours` option of the `plt.table` function.

You can map unique colors to each name using the `race_order` DataFrame. You have to figure out how the names are sorted in your graphs, for the example I used the order of the first column (Segment1). Thus you can map the name to the colors of the default palette (in my case "tab10"):

```
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex
race_order.replace(dict(zip(race_order.Segment_1, map(to_hex, plt.get_cmap('tab10').colors)))).values
```

which outputs:

```
array([['#1f77b4', '#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e'],
       ['#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#1f77b4'],
       ['#2ca02c', '#ff7f0e', '#d62728'],
       ['#d62728', '#d62728', '#2ca02c']], dtype=object)
```

which gives us, in the context of your code:

```
from matplotlib.colors import to_hex
table = plt.table(cellText=race_order.values,
                  colLabels=race_order.columns,loc='center',
                  cellColours=race_order.replace(dict(zip(race_order.Segment_1, map(to_hex, plt.get_cmap('Set1').colors)))).values
                 )
```

[image: colored table]