# How to show a pandas styled LaTeX table as plot insert

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, latex

I would like to show a (LaTeX) table *in* a Matplotlib graph.  I have generated the LaTeX source for the table by styling a Pandas `DataFrame`, and am attempting to add that to my graph using the `Axes.text` method.  However, the code is failing with what seems to be some kind of LaTeX interpretation error.

Here's what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 4) * np.array([1, 2, 2, 0.5]) + np.array([0, 4, 9, 11]), 
                  columns=['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'])

stats = df.describe()
stats.index = [idx.replace('%', 'p') for idx in stats.index]

styled = stats.style\
    .background_gradient(cmap=sns.blend_palette(['xkcd:red', 'white', 'xkcd:green'], as_cmap=True), 
                         vmin=-15, vmax=15, 
                         subset=pd.IndexSlice[['mean', 'min', '25p', '50p', '75p', 'max'], :])\
    .background_gradient(cmap=sns.blend_palette(['white', 'xkcd:purple'], as_cmap=True), 
                         vmin=0, vmax=3, subset=pd.IndexSlice['std', :])\
    .format(lambda v: f'{v:0.2f}')\
    .format(lambda v: f'{v:0.0f}', subset=pd.IndexSlice['count', :])

s = styled.to_latex(
    clines="skip-last;data",
    convert_css=True,
    position_float="centering",
    multicol_align="|c|",
    hrules=True
).replace('\n', ' ')

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{etoolbox} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage[table]{xcolor} \usepackage{colortbl} \usepackage{siunitx} \usepackage{longtable} \usepackage{graphics}')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 6))
df.plot(kind='hist', ax=ax, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.4, bins=50)
ax.set_xlim([-6, 15])
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
ax.text(0.02, 0.98, s, ha='left', va='top', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

The graphing works fine *except for* the inclusion of the styled table.  I get this result, which is clearly not correct.

[image: Table w styling problems]

I'm hoping for something more like this to show up on the Axes.
[image: Properly styled table]

Comment: Might be easier to save the table as an image, and then show it on the figure with https://stackoverflow.com/q/65387500/7758804. It should be noted, that it will be confusing if the table uses colors similar to the plot (green and red) but those colors have different meanings than the legend. There's really not a good reason to color the summary statistics, particularly the way the highlighting is done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63387275/7758804 is an option from 2020 fore exporting the styled table to an image.

Comment: Appreciate the answers, but not looking for a workaround.  Any idea why the table shows but doesn't seem to handle the color directives properly?

Comment: The latex is just a string, and matplotlib probably doesn't know how to render `{\\cellcolor[HTML]{73D076}} \\color[HTML]{000000} 9.00`. It seems you can do an image, as previously suggested, or a plain text table as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531491/7758804

Comment: Also, I see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68196610/7758804, but this is a table, below a plot.

Comment: I hope this is not a too stupid question but, as it is [said in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html) do you have a functional LaTeX installation and if you are in Windows, is it in the PATH?

Comment: Yes, it's functional.  Note that there is indeed some LaTeX rendering happening in the upper-left of the axes area.  It's just not handling the cell coloring correctly.

Comment: Can confirm the `s` string does compile fine with colors, but not inside matplotlib

Comment: A simple `plt.text(0.5, 0.5, r"${ \color[HTML]{AA54AA} \textrm{This is some text} }$")` does not work also, but works if creating a file with `plt.savefig("fig.ps")`, see [related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310241/latex-colors-not-rendered-in-matplotlib-text).

Comment: @paime can you confirm whether you can get my full example to work with the `ps` trick?

Comment: unfortunately the full example didn't work with ps trick, I didn't look further though

Comment: seems to come from the `position_float` arg of the `styled.to_latex()`, if you remove it it works, but font seems not applied, idk why

Comment: and say I need something more "normal" than `.ps` as my output format...if I replace the "save as .ps" with "save as .pdf" it doesn't work.  Very frustrating!  Is there a way to convert the ps to an image file in a second step that won't break it?  I'll add a bounty to this tomorrow, but would love to know, behind the scenes, why this doesn't "just work".